# How to display 3 UitableviewCells with 3 different cellIdentifiers in the singleviewcontroller in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a singleview controller , in that 3 buttons are there,
 Let us assume A,B,C tabs and when i click on Tab "A", i need to display the `uitableview` cell  corresponding to that Cellidentifier
 I know how to implement for 2 `Uitableviewcell` , but i had more than two 
please help ,

```
 -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSString *CellIdentifier = @"";
        if (!A) {
            //Get the top cell
            CellIdentifier = @"Cell-IdentifierA";
        }
         else if (B)
        {
            //Get bottom cell
            CellIdentifier = @"Cell-IdentifierB";
        }
```

Comment: Show some code. As you have implemented 2 cell, same way add one more condition and you can integrate 3rd cell.

Comment: Are you working with prototype cell or xib

Comment: i am using storyboard @NiravD

Comment: No what I asking is where you have design all these three cells, have you made it with prototype cell or with XIB ?

Comment: with prototype @NiravD

Comment: @rajesh_Ios Then give all 3 cell's different reuseIdentifier and in TableViewDataSource method simply compare with button is currently selected and return the `tablViewCell`` according to it

Comment: if yu know the array bounds, then use static cells for your concept

Comment: Is your cell is same for all the three buttons. I mean tableView have same components at same place but data in tableview is diff as per the tab Button.

Comment: no i am using different cells for  three buttons @dahiya_boy

Comment: Have you google once ? It very basic concept! you just need to do some r&d and need to learn more about how `tableView` works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a global variable

```
NSString *selectedCell = @"FirstCellIdentifier"
```

On click of each button

```
selectedCell = @"newCellIdentifier" //and reload tableview
```

And finally in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([selectedCell isEqualToString:@"FirstCellIdentifier"]) {
         return firstCell
    } else if ([selectedCell isEqualToString:@"SecondCellIdentifier"]) {
         return secondCell
    } else if ([selectedCell isEqualToString:@"ThirdCellIdentifier"]) {
         return thirdCell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

 /*Load Number of cells according to the selected button state*/

     if (btnA.selected){
        return arrA.count;
      }
      else if (btnB.selected){
        return arrB.count;
     }
     else {
        return arrC.count;
     }

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   /*Load Cell according to the Button selected state*/

   if (btnA.selected){
         UITableViewCell *cellA = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellA"];
         return cellA;
      }
      else if (btnB.selected){
         UITableViewCell *cellA = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellA"];
         return cellA;
     }
     else {
         UITableViewCell *cellC = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellC"];
         return cellC;
     }
}

 /*mantain your button state like*/

//buttnA Action

btnA.selected = true;
btnB.selected = false;
btnC.selected = false;
tableView.reloadData();

//buttnB Action
btnA.selected = false;
btnB.selected = true;
btnC.selected = false;
tableView.reloadData();

//buttnC Action
btnA.selected = false;
btnB.selected = false;
btnC.selected = true;
tableView.reloadData();
```

If you still have doubt you can ask.